# Redirect all subdomain page to a domain page

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have three subdomains and I want to redirect all my subdomains registration page to my domain registration page in .htaccess for wordpress multisite. I am using the below code but it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain1\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain2\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain3\.com$
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need `[OR]` conditions to make this work otherwise your conditions will always fail since `HTTP_HOST` cannot be equal to all the 3 sub-domains at the same time:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain1\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain2\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain3\.com$
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Another shorter way:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(sub\.domain1\.com|sub\.domain2\.com|sub\.domain3\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^register/(.*)$ http://domain.com/register/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: This is not PHP code. This must be placed as first rule in your main .htacess file

Comment: I use cloudflare and for some reason this doesn't work. Can i get a code for wp-config.php?

Comment: Sorry this question is based on .htaccess so solution is also for that. What URL is not working and what is the error? Better you show your complete .htaccess in question.

Answer (score 0):

In your sub-domains registration page, add the following code:

```
wp_redirect( 'http://www.yourDomain.com', 301 ); 
exit;
```